# How can I diagnose a tgkill:Abort exception detected in an Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin

The monitoring system (Sentry) of my Android app detected a `tgkill:Abort` issue with the following stacktrace.

```
OS Version: Android 7.1.2 (20211008.184132)
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: Unknown (SIGABRT)

Application Specific Information:
Abort

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libc.so                         0xb5ff5eb8          tgkill
1   libc.so                         0xb5ff3633          pthread_kill
2   libc.so                         0xb5fc97f5          raise
3   libc.so                         0xb5fc5331          <unknown> + 3053212465
4   libc.so                         0xb5fc32e8          abort
5   libart.so                       0xb412cf89          art::Runtime::Abort
6   libart.so                       0xb3ec7285          art::LogMessage::~LogMessage
7   libart.so                       0xb3fce4bb          art::IndirectReferenceTable::Add
8   libart.so                       0xb4075af5          <unknown> + 3020380917
9   libandroid_runtime.so           0xb58ff44f          android::NotifyHandler::handleMessage
10  libutils.so                     0xb4533df9          android::Looper::pollInner
11  libutils.so                     0xb4533b7f          android::Looper::pollOnce
12  libandroid_runtime.so           0xb5903efd          android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce
13  system@framework@boot.oat       0x741019ad          oatexec
```

The device OS is Android 7.1.2. All customers has the same model and version [Telpo TPS470](https://www.telpo.com.cn/biometric-device/biometric-tablet.html).

I'm not able to reproduce the issue in my devices. Is there a way to understand what's causing the exception?

The app is a time attendance system. It runs for long period of time (more than one day) listening for NFC card. No images or complex UI is involved. The app uses AndroidX, Compose, Room, WorkManager, Kotlin coroutines, Hilt.

Do you know what could cause the issue or just how to diagnose it?